# Web page summary with Ruby

Tags: ruby, summary

Can anyone recommend a Ruby library for creating a summary of a given URL?  What I have in mind is the sort of one- or two-sentence summary as seen in search engine results.

Comment: Can you elaborate more via example?

Comment: Consider Bing search results: http://www.bing.com/search?q=linux+console+editor  The first hit has the following summary:

"In this edition of Linux Explorers, we're picking your text editor for you. ... Make a new file called "tessst" by opening a console and typing this ..."

I want to be able to come up with a summary like that for any arbitrary URL that I give.  I have already considered webscraping search engine results, but the problem there is that sometimes a given page may not have been indexed (due to reasons such as newness, or robots.txt).

Answer (score 1):

You could you just scrape the web page for either description meta tag or if that's not available the first few sentences from the first `<p>` element on the page. The description meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Nokogiri (鋸) is an HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parser with XPath and CSS selector support." />
```

There's several Ruby libraries for parsing HTML. I hear that [Nokogiri](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2008/10/30/nokogiri-is-released/) is good for this sort of stuff, but I have no experience with it personally.

Comment: That sounds like a good strategy for a first stab.  And I've used Nokogiri a number of times in the past; it is my lib of choice for webscraping.  Thanks for your response, Mark.

Comment: It's not safe to assume `<p>` tags will exist. These days, pages often use `<div>` or `<span>` to mimic paragraphs, and their position on the page could be anywhere. For search-engines, the content is supposed to be at the top, but there are ways to work around that and maintain search-ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Spidering a site and scraping pages is easy. Summarizing a page is difficult.

The metatags can help a little, as there is supposed to be a direct correlation between the summary and the content.

Unfortunately, not all pages have them, and many that do are inaccurate. That leaves us with having to scape text, hoping that it's pertinent to the content and context. Page layouts vary and there is no standard saying where on a page the main content actually lies and, because of CSS and Ajax, it might not be where we'd expect it, in the first couple lines of text. There might not be `<p>` tags, as a `<div>` or `<span>` with the appropriate CSS can replace the look.

I've written many spiders that did contextual analysis of the pages, trying to summarize, and it's ugly and not bullet-proof, especially when dealing with the English language because of homonyms, synonyms, and other "nyms" that get in the way.

If you can locate text to summarize, there are decent tools to reduce several paragraphs, or a paper, into a short sentence. Mac OS comes with a summarizer, and has for years. "[Summarize Text Using Mac OSX Summarize Or Microsoft Word AutoSummarize](http://www.documentsnap.com/summarize-text-using-mac-osx-summarize-or-microsoft-word-autosummarize/)" talks about enabling it if you want to experiment. "[Mac 101: Shorten text using the Summarize Service](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/11/19/mac-101-shorten-text-using-the-summarize-service/)" is about using it on the Mac. There's a driver or app for it that can be called from the CLI. See "[How to use Mac OS X's Summary Service on the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/82287/how-to-use-mac-os-xs-summary-service-on-the-command-line)" for more info.

And, as a demo, here's [Lincoln's Gettysburg address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address) summarized to one line:

> It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us—that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion—that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain—that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom—and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.